# Membership renewal issues - Can a renewal payment date by set as membership start date?

Tags: civimember, recurring-contributions, auto-renew

We uncovered a potential workflow issue in our configuration with regards to membership issues.

As we migrated to CiviCRM, we had users on an offline payment processor, and once this expired we asked them to move over to an online payment processor such as Stripe or GoCardless.

As an example, a user's offline membership expired on 25th January 2019 and they renewed online via Stripe on the 18th of February 2019. This Stripe was an annual membership with a recurring contribution.

It's now 2020, and the user received our scheduled reminder 'Your membership has expired' on the 24th of January. The original offline membership date. This confused the user because a) it came earlier than her last payment date and b) expected it not to expire at all because they had the recurring contribution set up.

Investigating it further shows that the membership had indeed expired. But the recurring contribution via Stripe is still active and set up to renew on the 17th of February 2020.

Is there any way to change this so that a membership renewal that occurs some time after it's expired renews the membership from that latest payment date? Otherwise, this gap between expiry and auto-renewing payment is always going to exist. Each member is going to enter the expired email workflow, even though they have a recurring payment and in reality, aren't expiring.

We have a large number of other existing members who will migrate across to the recurring payments managed on CiviCRM and would likely encounter the same problem.

Any help would be much appreciated! Thanks.

Comment: Would you be able to add some screenshots of the recurring contribution record and of the membership?  It sounds like the new recurring payment wasn't correctly tied to the membership and thus didn't update the status.

Comment: A couple of options, extend the grace period (not ideal but will stop the membership expiring). Another option would be to move the end dates to be inline with the payment plan, in effect giving some free membership. The plus side of this approach is that everything lines up (end dates and payment expected dates etc). We have a few other work arounds to this but our normal approach is either of the above.

Comment: Thanks @ParvezSaleh - That's exactly what we've decided to do - extend the membership to the new recurring payment date, seems the most cost-effective way of doing it in the short term.